# Ubuntu on ThinkPad X1 Carbon with High DPI display

Tags: 13.10

I have a ThinkPad X1 Carbon on order and I want to install Ubuntu 13.10. Is there a step by step guide to make this work with UEFI? I've read that I have to change the BIOS, and I've also read that changing the BIOS is unnecessary. There is a lot of conflicting information out there. Where is the definitive resource?

Also, does anyone have any experience getting Ubuntu to run properly on high DPI displays? Is there a terminal command that will scale everything so it isn't tiny on a 2560x1440 display?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you don't need to mess with the BIOS - Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 should both have U/EFI support.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to trying it when the ThinkPad is delivered. Do you have any idea about whether 13.10 will scale on that display?

Comment: I am guessing that you can use the "Universal Access" options and increase text size... that should help.